# bridging header problem compiling project on Mac mini despite compiling and running perfectly on macBookPro

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header, xcode9.4

[image: errors compiling on Mac mini]

I am running this project on my MBP and works fine , upon pulling from the repo or even copying the entire project to my Mac mini the errors in the image happen .
I am sure it works (verified adding the bridging header correctly and setting the appropriate flags in the build settings for the target as it works on the MBP)

my project is in swift , the library to import is written in objective c and I am running Xcode 9.4.1 on both machines

any help is appreciated

edit : 
 - I tried uninstalling and reinstalling macOS and Xcode and the error still persisted 
 - error msgs : "/Users/******/Desktop/folderName/folderName/Bridging-Header.h:9:9: error: 'PayFortSDK/PayFortSDK.h' file not found

## import

```
    ^
```

1 error generated.
:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hjvpkqxmenpclmebdbrkxcarqoap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Bridging-Header-swift_27LSG8YDJOKNN-clang_13WCR1S0OL464.pch' for bridging header '/Users/******/Desktop/folderName/folderName/Bridging-Header.h'"

**EDIT** : **found solution :** 
1- deleted framework files and old bridging header 
2- added new bridging header with a new name and modified the name in buildSettings 
3- added framework files again under Frameworks 
4- some files had different targets(main target - testing targets) / unified all files targets  
5-clean/ index / build Succedded

**SecondEDIT** : ** another branch / same project ** 
there was another bridging header is the project folder that was not added to the project after deleting it everything worked as expected

Comment: Always add code, error messages, etc as text - so they're searchable, and can be copied when writing an answer.

Comment: Do you use pods? Make sure to open the `.xcworkspace` project instead of the normal one.

Comment: I am positive i am using the .xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

check your build settings, there is your bridging header path is set or not and then also clean your derivedData Folder,then clean and run your project

Comment: tried this , even went as far as checking the build settings on the Mac mini vs the MBP  side to side , nothing different .
then copied the entire project , still did not work ,
pulling from GitHub also does not work